# Java generic List with genric items as parameter

Tags: java, generics

I have the following interface with generic and an implentation class:

```
public interface DataInterface<T> {
    T getData();
    void printData();
}
```

```
public class IntegerData implements DataInterface<Integer> {

    private Integer value;
    
    public IntegerData(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getData() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void printData() {
        System.out.println(this.value);        
    }

}
```

And here my code that use the class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<IntegerData> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        dataList.add(new IntegerData(1));
        
        doSomething(dataList); <-- Compiler error
        
        //this work
        doSomething(Collections.unmodifiableList(dataList));
        doSomething(new ArrayList<>(dataList));
    }
    
    private static void doSomething(List<DataInterface<?>> dataList) {
        for (DataInterface<?> data : dataList)
            data.printData();
    }
}
```

If I try to call the doSomething method with the List type, the compiler complains with "The method doSomething(List<DataInterface<?>>) in the type Main is not applicable for the arguments (List)".

But if I wrap my specific list or create a new one, then it works. I wonder why the direct call doesn't work. What is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `List<IntegerData>` or `List<DataInterface<Integer>>` is not compatible with `List<DataInterface<?>>`, because I can also add a `DataInterface<String>` to the latter. The solution is to use extends:

```
private static void doSomething(List<? extends DataInterface<?>> dataList)
```

This will prevent adding anything to the list (except `null`), and is therefore safe to use.

By wrapping the list, the generic type is changed due to type inference. If you'd assign it to a variable using `var` it would also fail.